# ReactJS: Is it possible to get the state value in constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a component with an input field. Typing any value will send this into a state field (`searchString`).

Now I need to get this state value into my constructor as it should be send as a parameter to my subscription:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('images', this.state.searchString) // <-- How to get state value?
        this.state = {
            ready       : subscription.ready(),
            subscription: subscription,
            searchString: ''
        }
    }

    searchImage(event) {
        const searchString = event.target.value
        this.setState({ searchString })
    }

    render() {
        const posts = Collection.find({}).fetch()
        return (<Input onChange={ this.searchImage.bind(this) }/>)
    }
}

export default Example
```

I tried to log the value into the console, but I can't get the state object:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this)       // I do get context, props, refs, state and updater objects
    console.log(this.state) // I do get `undefined`, but in the line above I do see state object with all fields
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('images')
    this.state = {
        ready       : subscription.ready(),
        subscription: subscription,
        searchString: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: if you logged `this.state` after its initialization you will be able to get. I tried to put a break point after `console.log(this)`, and it's not showing the `state`, until it's already defined. I do not know what is happening here, but I guess it gets `this` gets updating while logging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be storing property in state, if you are not mutating it. That apply also for storing redux data to your state. Dont duplicate data.
Iam dont know if subscribe is asynchronious so the code setting should be as its callback

Not sure about the subscribing though, if you wanna do it just once? By the logic of your code, you are subscribing on every change of the search field. If it should happen only on first render, use component(Did/Will) mount cycle

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ready       : false,
            subscription: null,
            searchString: ''
        }
    }

    searchImage(event) {
        const searchString = event.target.value
        // Iam not sure, if subscribe is asynchronious so the code setting should be as its callback
        const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('images', searchString)
        this.setState({
          searchString,
          subscription,
          ready: subscription.ready();
        })
    }

    render() {
        const posts = Collection.find({}).fetch()
        return (<Input onChange={ this.searchImage.bind(this) }/>)
    }
}

export default Example
```

Comment: I don't want to subscribe to all images on mounting the component. Instead I would like to subscribe for those images depending on the input value. That's why I am using a parameter for the subscription. Is there a better way to limit the subscription/publication?

Comment: I dont actualy know what you wanna achieve, so it is hard for me to answer that :/ The best way though it is through componentDidMount() cycle as I mentioned, if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is called only once in a lifecycle. So once you update the state constructor would not be called.

Comment: So where should I put the subscription?

Comment: you can use it in componentDidUpdate method. It would be called after every updation in the component.